# How to enable the home button to return to a common activity?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, back-stack, android-homebutton

I use [ActionbarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com) and would like to enable the home button ...
Therefore I call `setHomeButtonEnabled(true)` in my base activity.

```
public class BaseFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); // Here
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home: {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
                // startActivity(intent);
                // startActivityIfNeeded(intent, 0);
                return true;
            }
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

When I use `startActivity(intent)` or `startActivityIfNeeded(intent, 0)` the `HomeActivity` is recreated everytime (the activity renders a map and recreating it is annoying).

- I do not want to [call `finish()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11617537/356895) since it just takes me back one step in the app hierarchy. Instead I always want to return to the `HomeActivity`.
- Further it would be nice if the behavior could be configured in `AndroidManifest.xml` as it is described for the [ActionBar and setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home).
- It might also be common sense to **clear the backstack** when I return to the `HomeActivity`. What is your opinion on that?

Comment: make your home activity as singleInstance, and user startActivity(intent), It will bring your old home activity instance into front

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Android documentation I found what I was searching for: You can set the [flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to clear the back stack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP). The second [flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` avoid restarting the activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) if used in combination with the flag mentioned before.

```
case android.R.id.home: {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivityIfNeeded(intent, 0);
    return true;
}
```

The intent needs to be passed using [`startActivityIfNeeded()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityIfNeeded%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29).

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider using the single instance launchmode for that activity.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity  android:launchMode="singleInstance">
...
</activity>
```

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestActivity_launchMode)

> Only allow one instance of this activity to ever be running. This
>   activity gets a unique task with only itself running in it; if it is
>   ever launched again with the same Intent, then that task will be
>   brought forward and its Activity.onNewIntent() method called. If this
>   activity tries to start a new activity, that new activity will be
>   launched in a separate task. See the Tasks and Back Stack document for
>   more details about tasks.